# How to compute the hopping matrix considering the change of multiple states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling, matrix-elements

My question is quite simple, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Hubbard Models usually have a hopping term as follow:

$$H_{hop} = -t \sum_{<i,j>} \left( c^{\dagger}_{j} c_{i} + c^{\dagger}_{i} c_{j} \right)$$

Considering the basis is made of |0,0,0,0> , |0,0,0,1>, ..., |1,1,0,0>, |1,0,1,0>, ..., |1,1,1,1>, I must use $<\phi_i| H_{hop} | \phi_j>$ to compute the matrix elements. For example:

$$<1,0,0,0| H_{hop} | 0,1,0,0 > = -t$$

My question is: can I change the state of more than one site at once, and what am I going to find as the matrix element? I thought I could find something like this:

$$<0,0,1,1| H_{hop} | 1,1,0,0 > = -2t$$

$$<1,1,1,0| H_{hop} | 0,1,1,1 > = -3t$$

But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: After acting the Hamiltonian on a basis state, the inner product of this expansion with any basis state can only lead to the contribution of AT MOST ONE term from the original expansion. Therefore, no.

Comment: I recommend first doing this *absolutely explicitly* for three sites. That is, act directly with the operators on the states and see what happens. That will give you a good feeling for what's going on mathematically, and you can match that to the physics of the situation.